# How can i get custom switch checkbox value in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

here my edit modal :

```
<form autocomplete="off" novalidate
    action="<?= base_url('app/admin/user-editData')?>"
    method="POST">
    <input type="hidden"
        name="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>"
        value="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="PhoneNo"
                class="form-control"
                value="<?= $data1->PhoneNo; ?>"
                placeholder="<?= $this->lang->line('enter');?> <?= $this->lang->line('phonenumber');?>"
                required
                data-validation-required-message="<?php echo $this->lang->line('required');?>"
                data-validation-containsnumber-regex="(\d)+"
                minlength="11" maxlength="13"
                data-validation-containsnumber-message="<?php echo $this->lang->line('valid_numeric');?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div
            class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-success switch-md mr-2 mb-1">
            Mobile Activated
            &nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
                id="customSwitch80">
            <label class="custom-control-label"
                for="customSwitch80">
                <span class="switch-text-left"
                    value="Y"><?= $this->lang->line('yes');?></span>
                <span class="switch-text-right"
                    value="N"><?= $this->lang->line('no');?></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div
            class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-success switch-md mr-2 mb-1">
            Website Activated
            &nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
                id="customSwitch0">
            <label class="custom-control-label"
                for="customSwitch0">
                <span class="switch-text-left"
                    value="Y"><?= $this->lang->line('yes');?></span>
                <span class="switch-text-right"
                    value="N"><?= $this->lang->line('no');?></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary"><?= $this->lang->line('save');?></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have database field called WebActivated and also MobileActivated.

Example :

WebActivated status is "Y" in database (enum Y or N datatype)

How can the switch in "yes" position when the modal opened?

then i swith the status become "no" then how can i store value "N" in database?

Sorry for bad english. correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to check when the `checkbox` status is changed and then make an `ajax` call to update the value in the `database`.

```
 $('#customSwitch0').change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) { // checked
        var check = 'Y';

    }else{ // not checked
        var check = 'N';
    }
    $.ajax({ // start ajax call
        url: "<?php your-url-here ?>", // location to your controller, update table there, and return 1 or 0(Json values)
        dataType: "JSON",  // expects json to be returned
        method: "POST", 
        data: {'check': check} // send the value to be updated, will be accessible through $this->input->post('check');
        success: function(msg){
            // check condition for success or fail ie. 1 or 0
            // do something here
        }
    });
});
```

Same code for mobile updated (id = `customSwitch80`)
See if it helps you.